# git, strange upstream entry which i cant get rid of

Tags: windows, git, github

if i do

```
git remote -v
```

i get

```
origin  https://..../foo.git (fetch)
origin  https://..../foo.git (push)
upstream
```

this last upstream line there prevents me from adding a real upstream which i wanna merge from.

my config file looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://..../foo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

when i do

```
git fetch upstream
```

i get this error:

```
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

how can i get rid of that upstream?

Comment: Have you tried `git remote rm upstream`?

Comment: thanks but if i do that i get: `error: Could not remove config section 'remote.upstream' `

Comment: Add a fake one (copy the `origin` part) and try again :-D

Comment: adding the fake one worked. also removing it works. but that leads to the config file being the same as before and that single upstream entry is there again.

Answer (score 1):

Git has several scopes where config is set : `system` (`$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`), `global` (`~/.gitconfig`) and `local` (`.git/config` of the current repository).

Since there is nothing about `upstream` in your `local` scope, you have to check the `system` and `global` scopes. It could simply be a write access permission to associated files.

Comment: besides the name and email, there is nothing in the global .gitconfig

Comment: And nothing in GIT_INSTALL_DIR/etc/gitconfig ?